# If has class in child element return true with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="media">
    <div id="table-pane">
        <img src="..." class="img-thumbnail">
        <img src="..." class="img-thumbnail selected">
        <img src="..." class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want If has selected class in child element return true. My codes

```
 $("#media").hasClass('.selected');
```

Always return false ???

Comment: Needs to be `return true` / `return false`? But what is the actual question? Doesn't look like your code would be doing much.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: if there is not a function you cant return any value...

Comment: @Roy `.each(function...` is a function?

Comment: my code is not work

Comment: i want if has selected class return true else false

Comment: No period in `.hasClass()` arguments. Should be `.hasClass('selected')` not `.hasClass('.selected')`

Comment: thank you man if ($("#media img").hasClass('selected')) { worked !

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
            if($('#media').children().children().hasClass('selected')){
                alert('class was found');
            }else{
                alert('class was not found');
            }

        })
```